# C++ Class Composition - When does constructors and destructors get executed

Tags: c++, class, constructor, composition

PLEASE HELP! I know the question is lengthy, but I sincerely don't have anybody who can help me understand the concept.

I have a code from a book, but I sincerely could not understand the output at all. The code is an example regarding two classes composition, and in what order the constructors and destructors are executed.

Sorry for lengthy example:

```
// Fig. 10.8: Date.h
// Date class definition; Member functions defined in Date.cpp
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date
{
    public:
    static const unsigned int monthsPerYear = 12; // number of months in a year
    explicit Date( int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900 ); // default constructor
    void print() const; // print date in month/day/year format
    ~Date(); // provided to confirm destruction order

private:
    unsigned int month; // 1-12 (January-December)
    unsigned int day; // 1-31 based on month
    unsigned int year; // any year

    // utility function to check if day is proper for month and year
    unsigned int checkDay( int ) const;
}; // end class Date

#endif

// Fig. 10.9: Date.cpp
// Date class member-function definitions.
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Date.h" // include Date class definition
using namespace std;

// constructor confirms proper value for month; calls
// utility function checkDay to confirm proper value for day
Date::Date( int mn, int dy, int yr )
{
    if ( mn > 0 && mn <= monthsPerYear ) // validate the month
        month = mn;
    else
        throw invalid_argument( "month must be 1-12" );

    year = yr; // could validate yr
    day = checkDay( dy ); // validate the day

    // output Date object to show when its constructor is called
    cout << "Date object constructor for date ";
    print();
    cout << endl;
} // end Date constructor

    // print Date object in form month/day/year
void Date::print() const
{
    cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << year;
} // end function print

// output Date object to show when its destructor is called

Date::~Date()
{
    cout << "Date object destructor for date ";
    print();
    cout << endl;
} // end ~Date destructor

// utility function to confirm proper day value based on // month and     year; handles leap years, too
unsigned int Date::checkDay( int testDay ) const
{
    static const array < int, monthsPerYear + 1 > daysPerMonth =
        { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    // determine whether testDay is valid for specified month
    if ( testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[ month ] )
        return testDay;

    // February 29 check for leap year
    if ( month == 2 && testDay == 29 && ( year % 400 == 0 || ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 ) ) )
        return testDay;

    throw invalid_argument( "Invalid day for current month and year" );
} // end function checkDay

// Fig. 10.10: Employee.h
// Employee class definition showing composition. // Member functions     defined in Employee.cpp.
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <string>
//#include "Date.h" // include Date class definition using namespace std;
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee( const string &, const string &, const Date &, const Date & );
    void print() const;
    ~Employee(); // provided to confirm destruction order
private:
    string firstName; // composition: member object
    string lastName; // composition: member object
    const Date birthDate; // composition: member object
    const Date hireDate; // composition: member object 23
}; // end class Employee

#endif

// Fig. 10.11: Employee.cpp
// Employee class member-function definitions.
#include <iostream>
#include "Employee.h" // Employee class definition
#include "Date.h" // Date class definition
using namespace std;

// constructor uses member initializer list to pass initializer
// values to constructors of member objects
Employee::Employee( const string &first, const string &last, const Date &dateOfBirth, const Date &dateOfHire )
: firstName( first ), lastName( last ), birthDate( dateOfBirth ), hireDate( dateOfHire )
{
    // output Employee object to show when constructor is called
    cout << "Employee object constructor: " << firstName << ' ' << lastName << endl;
} // end Employee constructor

// print Employee object
void Employee::print() const
{
    cout << lastName << ", " << firstName << " Hired: ";
    hireDate.print();

    cout << " Birthday: ";
    birthDate.print();

    cout << endl;
} // end function print

// output Employee object to show when its destructor is called
Employee::~Employee()
{
    cout << "Employee object destructor: " << lastName << ", " << firstName << endl;
} // end ~Employee destructor

// Fig. 10.12: fig10_12.cpp
// Demonstrating composition--an object with member objects.
#include <iostream>
//#include "Employee.h" // Employee class definition
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Date birth( 7, 24, 1949 );
    Date hire( 3, 12, 1988 );
    Employee manager( "Bob", "Blue", birth, hire );

    cout << endl;
    manager.print();
}//endmain
```

I know the code is too long, but really couldn't think of a way to do this easier. The output is below.

```
Date object constructor for date 7/24/1949
Date object constructor for date 3/12/1988
Employee object constructor: Bob Blue

Blue, Bob  Hired: 3/12/1988  Birthday: 7/24/1949
Employee object destructor: Blue, Bob
Date object destructor for date 3/12/1988
Date object destructor for date 7/24/1949
Date object destructor for date 3/12/1988
Date object destructor for date 7/24/1949
```

Now, my question is...
Why is constructor of date object is only executed twice while the destructor is executed four times? To my understanding, the constructor of Date object should also be executed four times:
  1. Upon 'Date birth(7, 24, 1949)' in main
  2. Upon 'Date hire(3, 12, 1988)' in main
  3. Upon 'const Date birthDate' in Employee.h
  4. Upon 'const Date hireDate' in Employee.h

The reason for my #3 and #4 is that I can't imagine Employee object constructor to copy 'birth' and 'hire' without same type of empty variables(or Date object in this case).
So, my understanding is that in Employee header, upon private member Date object creation, explicit default Date constructor should be executed once for each of them (with 1/1/1900 as member variables mn, dy, yr).

Comment: Cases 3 and 4 use the copy-constructor of `Date` which does not have any `cout` statement in it. Obviously it cannot be using the `Date( int mn, int dy, int yr )` because you never had any code to invoke that constructor with arguments

Comment: if you changed `birthDate( dateOfBirth ),` to `birthDate( dateOfBirth.month, dateOfBirth.day, dateOfBirth.year ), ` it would use that constructor

Comment: I have not yet understood the concept of copy-constructor yet. However, based on your comment, I would assume that the member variable definition and initialization do not necessarily create empty variable with the same type, am I correct?
Or, it does create empty variable with the same type, but just simply through different constructor (called copy constructor)?
If so, how about non-class variables like string and int? Do they get created in different manner or since they are not class, normal declaration is executed?

Comment: There's no such thing as "empty variable".   Uninitialized variables with class type must be created via a constructor.  (`std::string` is a class type). Primitive types can take indeterminate value which means they must be assigned a value before they can be used.

Comment: Where you wrote `birthdate( dateOfBirth )` it means "create `birthdate` using the constructor which takes argument `dateOfBirth`". That sort of constructor is called a copy-constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra 2 `Date` destructor calls are a result of `Employee` having 2 instances thereof.

When an `Employee` is destroyed, so are those instances.

Also, you are logging only the `Date(int,int,int)` constructor. The compiler provides a copy constructor for `Date`, which is used when initializing the 2 `Date` members of `Employee` with `const Date &`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to log the copy constructor calls, you will need to define the copy constructor yourself:

```
class Date
{
    unsigned month;
    unsigned day;
    unsigned year;

public:

    // Other stuff here

    explicit Date(int, int, int);

    Date(const Date &other) :
    //
    // Since this is a user-defined copy constructor,
    // all member initialization must be done explicitly.
    //
    month{other.month},
    day{other.day},
    year{other.year}
    {
        cout << "Date copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    // Rest of stuff here
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I simply have not got to the concept of copy-constructor yet. So, member object definition and initialization creates empty object with the same type, but just simply through different constructor (called copy constructor)? If so, how about non-class variables like string and int? Do they get created in different manner or since they are not class, normal declaration is executed?

Comment: The implicit copy constructor (the one supplied by the compiler) simply initializes all members with _their_ copy constructors, regardless of type. There are additional rules concerning where the compiler can actually generate an implicit constructor, though I'll spare you those details for now.

Comment: Wait! One more thing. I get that when an object is copied, copy constructor will be used. However, aren't the birthDate and hireDate created in header prior to being copied?
Since the Date objects are 'created' first than 'copied,' shouldn't user defined explicit constructor be used?

Comment: In the header they are merely declared: You have described them as members of a structure. Only within constructors are members initialized. Constructors are called wherever an instance has been declared.

Comment: You mean wherever an instance has been 'initialized?'
Please let it be 'initialized.' If so, things are clear.

Comment: Yes. Unless the member is `static`, it will only be initialized during a call to a constructor.